# Invalid XML: Error on line 454: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x8) was found in the CDATA section

Tags: java

When I parsed a rss url `https://shitapo.com/feed/` using rome `api "com.rometools:rome:1.15.0"` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://shitapo.com/feed/");
        XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlReader(url);
        SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(xmlReader);
    } catch (ConnectException connectException) {
        log.error("rss parse error", connectException);
    } catch (ParsingFeedException e) {
        System.out.println( e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("rss parse error", e);
    }
}
```

throw this error:

```
com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML: Error on line 454: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x8) was found in the CDATA section.
```

I could fix it my replace the `0x8` code, but is there any way to replace all invalid unicode code and make the different version of xml stream standard? Should I replace invalid code by different version of xml file? I found the XmlReader work but rome parsed failed.

Comment: Share the XML please (around line 454)

Answer (score 1):

I am tried to replace the spcial charactor and fix it like this:

```
public static String stripNonValidXMLCharacters(String in) {
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
        char current;

        if (in == null || ("".equals(in))) {
            return "";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
            current = in.charAt(i);
            if ((current == 0x9) || (current == 0xA) || (current == 0xD)
                    || ((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF))
                    || ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD))
                    || ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF))) {
                out.append(current);
            }
        }
        return out.toString();
    }
```

- step 1: fetch the string content from url
- step 2: replace the special charactor
- step 3: parse the standard string using rome